# Getting a string from another class not returning any results

Tags: c#

I've created a class that loads a crystalreport, to load my crystal report with the data from my access database I have another class which contains a form and textboxes which I am trying to use to query my database and return the desired results onto my report. I apologise for any spaghetti code, i'm quite new to this process. I'm also open for better implementation suggestions. I don't have any errors but when I try and load my crystal report with data from the 'ProviderNumber'(textBox3) textbox I get returned 0 results when i've used a providernumber that is in my database.

Class 1 (Contains the textbox for Provider Number)

```
    public partial class Doctor : Form
{
    public string PrvNum
    {
        get { return textBox3.Text; }
        set { textBox3.Text = value; }
    }
```

Class 2 (Generates the Crystal Report based on the Provider Number)

```
public partial class DoctorLetterPreview : Doctor
{
        public void LoadDoctorLetterPreview()
    {
        Doctor prvNum = new Doctor();
        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PathologyWest.accdb";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(" Select * from Doctors where ProviderNumber = @prvNum", con))
        {
            Command.Parameters.Add("@prvNum", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = prvNum.PrvNum;
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(Command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Doctors");
            MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString());
            con.Close();

            DoctorsLetter rpt = new DoctorsLetter();
            rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Tangentially related to your question, you are misusing inheritance. Your code acts as if `Doctor` is a different class, but `DoctorLetterPreview` actually _is_ a `Doctor`. This also doesn't make sense and is going to make your code base increasingly confusing if you don't fix this.

Comment: Is this in relation to public partial class DoctorLetterPreview : Doctor? I did this as it was the only way I could access textBox3 from the Doctor form

Comment: It's the only way _you could think of_. It is not the only way, nor is it a good way. Inheritance should only be used when "derivedclass is a baseclass" is correct ("a doctor letter preview is a doctor" - which is not correct) Hint: you can pass objects into methods, `public void LoadDoctorLetterPreview(Doctor doctor)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are creating a new instance of the form with

```
Doctor prvNum = new Doctor();
```

and then immediately try to access the form's textbox, which will be empty, since you just created the form.

It's hard to say what the whole thing looks like from here, but if you already have that form open in some way and have the value typed in the textbox, you should try to find that specific instance of the form and access that.

Comment: Thank you for that! you are exactly right. I have that form opened and I am attempting to access the value of textBox3 from within that form. The problem is that I cannot generate my report from using that form as my report lies within another form (DoctorsLetterPreview). Unless i'm mistaken about this and I can in fact manage that form from Doctor.cs

Comment: @Bergvid: I'm not meaning any offense. But based on your code and comments, you are missing important parts of what can be considered basic knowledge (OOP principles, when to use inheritance, ...) Your issue is the consequence of a chain of bad design decisions which you made because they were the only way you could think of achieving your goal. I strongly suggest that you revisit OOP basics in order to widen your repertoire so that you will know better solutions to problems you will be faced with, or else you're likely to repeatedly encounter problems from bad design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

On very beginning of your method `LoadDoctorLetterPreview()` you're making new instance of class `Doctor`, which means that you're making new `Form`. If that form is new, I'm guessing that it's `TextBox` named `textBox3` is empty. So, you're getting empty text as parameter in line `Command.Parameters.Add("@prvNum", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value`.

Instead of making new form, your method should either get reference to existing Doctor form, or you should, if that is the case, change line

```
Doctor prvNum = new Doctor();
```

into

```
Doctor prvNum = this;
```

telling that `prvNum` is in fact this form that this method is on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, you are correct my method is attempting to access the existing doctor form. I have changed this line and when submitting my method is returns a new doctor form hmm